# VBA code to convert heights

Tags: vba, excel

On an Excel spreadsheet order form, there is a column for heights. They need to be in a 3 digit format: 500, 506, 510, etc. I need a macro to convert the values in this column to follow that format.

I created these Subs, and it does work, but it's very slow and crashes Excel sometimes. I'd like to have something simpler that will run more quickly.

```
Sub FixHeights()
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        c = Replace(c, " ", "")
        c = Replace(c, "'", "")
        c = Replace(c, Chr(96), "")
        c = Replace(c, Chr(34), "")
        c = Replace(c, Chr(191), "")
        c = Replace(c, "'0", "")
        c = Replace(c, "'00", "")
    Next

    Call FixHeights2

End Sub

Sub FixHeights2()
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        c = Replace(c, "40", "400")
        c = Replace(c, "41", "401")
        c = Replace(c, "42", "402")
        c = Replace(c, "43", "403")
        c = Replace(c, "44", "404")
        c = Replace(c, "45", "405")
        c = Replace(c, "46", "406")
        c = Replace(c, "47", "407")
        c = Replace(c, "48", "408")
        c = Replace(c, "49", "409")
        c = Replace(c, "50", "500")
        c = Replace(c, "51", "501")
        c = Replace(c, "52", "502")
        c = Replace(c, "53", "503")
        c = Replace(c, "54", "504")
        c = Replace(c, "55", "505")
        c = Replace(c, "56", "506")
        c = Replace(c, "57", "507")
        c = Replace(c, "58", "508")
        c = Replace(c, "59", "509")
        c = Replace(c, "60", "600")
        c = Replace(c, "61", "601")
        c = Replace(c, "62", "602")
        c = Replace(c, "63", "603")
        c = Replace(c, "64", "603")
        c = Replace(c, "65", "605")
        c = Replace(c, "66", "606")
        c = Replace(c, "67", "607")
        c = Replace(c, "68", "608")
        c = Replace(c, "69", "609")
        c = Replace(c, "70", "700")
        c = Replace(c, "3010", "310")
        c = Replace(c, "4010", "410")
        c = Replace(c, "5010", "510")
        c = Replace(c, "6010", "610")
        c = Replace(c, "3011", "311")
        c = Replace(c, "4011", "411")
        c = Replace(c, "5011", "511")
        c = Replace(c, "6011", "611")
    Next
End Sub
```

My code strips out spaces, apostrophes, quotation marks, and instances of '0 and '00. Then, it converts the resulting values to a valid one.

Here are some examples of what would need to be converted. Basically, spaces, quotes, and apostrophes need to be taken out. And they all need to be 3 digit numbers: 508, 510, 600, etc.
5'6"
5'6
5'10"

Comment: Would a better way to think of this be: If you have a two digit number, you must insert a 0 in between the two numbers. For numbers greater than 2 digits in length, you want to remove the first occurrence of a `0`, starting from the left?

Comment: If the code works, I think it would be better to move this to [codereview.se] instead

Comment: What if you do not allow user to enter unwanted values using regular expression or even a function similar to those you created?

Comment: Can you post an example showing the kinds of formats the height might be entered?

Comment: @BruceWayne That is true. 6'2" should become 602, for example.

Comment: @Marco I wish we could do that, but it's not possible. Customers tend to copy and paste measurement information from their spreadsheet to our special ordering spreadsheet, and to make it easier for them to fill out, it's probably best to let them enter whatever they want.

Comment: Does the native replace method from Excel works faster than your code? I mean, CTRL + H. If it does, record a macro using this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to perform repeated replacements on each cell value.  In the best case scenario, you would only match one of them.  The worst case scenario is that you match *more* than one, which means that your output is going to be incorrect.  I'd just use a regular expression and then format the matches:

```
'Requires a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions x.x
Sub FixHeights()
    Dim c As Range
    With New RegExp
        Dim matches As MatchCollection
        .Pattern = "(\d+)\s*['`]\s*(\d+)"
        For Each c In Selection.Cells
            c.NumberFormat = "General"
            Set matches = .Execute(c.Value)
            If matches.Count = 1 Then 
                c.Value = CInt(matches.Item(0).SubMatches(0)) & _
                      Format$(CInt(matches.Item(0).SubMatches(1)), "00")
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get a compile error. "User-defined type not defined" I'm not familiar with regular expressions though, so maybe I'm not doing something right.

Comment: @Robby - Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions.  Tools->References.., check the box next to it in the list.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. Now when I run the code, I don't get an error, but nothing seems to happen either.

Comment: @Robby - Oops. See the edit - it should be `Set matches = .Execute(c.Value)`. I missed it when converting it from a function.

Comment: That works for the most part. I've thrown some scenarios at it, and it's like it stops processing the selected range when it gets to a value that is already valid. For example, if the very first cell in the selected column is already 506 or blank, it won't convert the rest of the column. Or if one of the heights halfway down the column is correct or blank, it doesn't convert the rest.